# Regular Expressions to Extract Non-Standard String

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, regex-lookarounds, stringr

My question has to do with using lookahead and lookbehind constructs in Regular Expressions with If-Then-Else Conditionals in combination with str_extract.

I have a string called UNIT in the table below that needs to be broken into its 3 component parts. The format is non-standard and I am using regex and str_extract to create new columns with each component.

I can easily extract the start (3A, 3C, etc.) and ends of the string (E, A), but the middle component is a bit more difficult. It can be 1-3 digits, or the two character code of SK, SD, or HH. I can use the code below individually, but the latter line overwrites the former.

**So, my question is, how can I use the If-Then-Else Conditionals in Regular Expressions (?(?=regex)then|else) in combination with str_extract to get df2 from df1?**

```
df1$C2 = str_extract(df1$UNIT,"(?<=[:upper:])\\d*(?<![:upper:])")

df1$C2 = str_extract(df1$UNIT, "S.$")


df1
ID  UNIT
1   3ASD
2   3C14E
3   3D5E
4   3E15E
5   3ESK
6   3B14A
7   3BHHQ2
8   3E101

df2
ID  UNIT    C1  C2  C3
1   3ASD    3A  SD  NA
2   3C14E   3C  14  E
3   3D5E    3D  5   E
4   3E15E   3E  15  E
5   3ESK    3E  SK  NA
6   3B14A   3B  14  A
7   3BHHQ2  3B  HH  Q2
8   3E101   3E  101 NA
```

Comment: Just to precise: the C2 value can only be 1 of 3 values, SK, SD, or HH, or 1-3 digits? And the C1 value is a digit + uppercase? And C3 is 1 uppercase that can be missing?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C2 value can be 1-3 digits (e.g., 5, 55, 555) or the three character pairs of SK, SD, HH. The character pairs are the only character types in C2. Correct, C3 is one uppercase that can be missing.

Comment: Well, C3 can be a letter + digit, #7 is `Q2`. Right? I think you may use `str_match`, try `str_match(df$UNIT, "^([0-9][[:upper:]])([0-9]{1,3}|S[KD]|HH)([[:upper:]][0-9]*)?$")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that code works but it is not getting the desired product shown in df2. I solved the problem and will post.

Comment: What is different there? You haven't provided a reproducible example, I built the DF myself, and the regex is matching the values fine given that you did not provide the exact specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can "encode" the conditions in a single regex wrapping the separate values with capturing groups and then use `str_match` to actually access those captures to later use them to create the columns:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), UNIT=c("3ASD","3C14E","3D5E","3E15E","3ESK","3B14A","3BHHQ2","3E101"))
rx = "^([0-9][[:upper:]])([0-9]{1,3}|S[KD]|HH)([[:upper:]][0-9]*)?$"
match_table <- str_match(df$UNIT, rx)
df$C1 <- match_table[,2]
df$C2 <- match_table[,3]
df$C3 <- match_table[,4]
> df
  ID   UNIT C1  C2   C3
1  1   3ASD 3A  SD <NA>
2  2  3C14E 3C  14    E
3  3   3D5E 3D   5    E
4  4  3E15E 3E  15    E
5  5   3ESK 3E  SK <NA>
6  6  3B14A 3B  14    A
7  7 3BHHQ2 3B  HH   Q2
8  8  3E101 3E 101 <NA>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sbxdTw/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9][[:upper:]])` - Group `C1`: a digit and then an uppercase letter
- `([0-9]{1,3}|S[KD]|HH)` - Group `C2`: 1, 2 or 3 digits, or `SK`, `SD` or `HH`
- `([[:upper:]][0-9]*)?` - an optional Group `C3`: an uppercase letter followed with 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string,

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and I am wondering why using str_match and creating match_table is preferable to str_extract. Is it a performance issue? I should mention that this dataset is >1M rows.

Comment: I do not know about the performance, since it is you who have the data. However, running a single regex once is less computational expensive than running it 3 times, and makes it more precise, since you do not have to worry about context (no need to use lookarounds or alternations with them). Basically, here, `str_match` is the KISS solution that is both safe and readable.

Comment: This approach works well, however there is one requirement that I missed. The Unit can also present itself with just the C1 format. For example, Unit = 3A, 3C. The regex as you wrote it will not pick up these instances. How would I integrate this added requirement into the code?

Comment: @samuelt It is extremely easy with `?` quantifier set to the second group (same as I have showed with the third group) - [`"^([0-9][[:upper:]])([0-9]{1,3}|S[KD]|HH)?([[:upper:]][0-9]*)?$"`](https://regex101.com/r/6Y7cEg/1)

Comment: That works well, thanks for the help. I have used the data table method.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in as a table:

```
 cbind(df1,read.table(text=sub("(..)(\\d+|SK|SD|HH)(.*)","\\1 \\2 \\3",df1$UNIT),fill=T,h=F,col.names = c("C1","C2","C3"),na.strings = ""))
  ID   UNIT C1  C2   C3
1  1   3ASD 3A  SD <NA>
2  2  3C14E 3C  14    E
3  3   3D5E 3D   5    E
4  4  3E15E 3E  15    E
5  5   3ESK 3E  SK <NA>
6  6  3B14A 3B  14    A
7  7 3BHHQ2 3B  HH   Q2
8  8  3E101 3E 101 <NA>
```

Comment: what is the benefit of reading it in as opposed to reading and then performing the operations?

Comment: I am assuming that the data you have has already been read in. so we can create a table out of the already read in data... if you find this difficult, you can do:`cbind(df1[1],do.call(rbind,regmatches(df1$UNIT,regexec("(..)(\\d+|SK|SD|HH)(.*)",df1$UNIT))))` which will still give the same results apart from the column names which you can set

Answer (score 0):

```
Problem solved using the following code:

        df2$C1=  str_extract(df1$Unit, "^[:digit:][:upper:]")
    #if the start of the string is a digit and upper case letter then extract it into col C1

        df2$C2= str_extract(df1$Unit,"(?<=[:upper:])\\d*(?<![:upper:])|(?<=[:upper:])[[:upper:]][[:upper:]](?<=[:upper:])")
    #if a digit follows an uppercase letter or is behind another uppercase letter then extract all digits in between and extract it into C2
    #OR if two uppercase letters follow an uppercase letter or come before another uppercase letter then extract all letters in between and extract it into C2

        df2$C3=  str_extract(df1$Unit, "(?<=[:digit:])[A-E]$|Q.$")
    #if a the last a letter is A-E and is preceded by a digit then extract the letter into C3
    #OR if the last character is preceded by the letter Q then extract Q and the character
```

Comment: You do not need the if else.. neither do you need to break them down. Just one regrex pattern is enough. Learn more about regrex and then you will understand what is given by Wiktor

Comment: And now compare with my example: 1) `C1`: yours is the same as mine, `^[:digit:][:upper:]` = `^([0-9][[:upper:]])` - start of string + uppercase, 2) you may 0+ digits/2 uppercase letters between 2 uppercase letters - BUT you said the uppercase letters are limited to `SK|SD|HH` - so, what to believe? 3) you may a letter from `A` to `E` at the end of the string, or `Q` followed with any char, e.g. with `§`. If that is correct specs, you should have provided it in the question. I think my solution is what you need - just precise the requirements.